# def и for, проблема с выводом последовательности

Tags: python, python-3.x

сижу экспериментирую, вместо перечисления букв выдает мне 'N o n e' по буквам

```
def func():
    input("Введите слово и мы разберем его по-буквам: ")
word= func()
word= str(word)
for letter in word:
    print(letter)

input("Press Enter")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def func():
    x = input("Введите слово и мы разберем его по-буквам: ")
    return x
word= func()
for letter in word:
    print(letter)
input("Press Enter")
```

Во-первых, почитайте о `return` в функциях и тогда поймёте почему у вас выводится None. Во-вторых, когда вы прописываете `input`, то всё введенное вами является строкой. Потому `word = str(word)` абсолютно бесполезная строка

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: Отметьте ответ галочкой, так другие пользователи увидят что на вопрос ответили